# Как правильно задавать аргументы args?

Tags: java, массивы

Хотел попробовать задать один аргумент `args[0]`, в зависимости от которого массив будет выводиться в прямом или обратном порядке.
На строке `if(args[0].compareTo("First") == 0)` выдает `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0`.

В чем проблема?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] massive = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        if (args[0].compareTo("First") == 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < massive.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(massive[i]);
            }
        }
        else if (args[0].compareTo("Second") == 0) {
            for (int i = massive.length; i > 0; i--) {
                System.out.println(massive[i]);
            }
        }
        else if (args[0] == null || args.length == 0) {
            System.out.println("Third");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: По коду, говорит что в args[] массиве нет элемента 0, по коду я самого args не вижу.

Comment: По идее args[0] будет задаваться в командной строке.

Comment: @Ibuprofenn покажите как вы из командной строки запускаете

Comment: @ЮрийСПб с командной строки не получилось запустить. Попробовал в Идее задать аргумент и наткнулся на ту самую ошибку. Без задания аргумента то же самое

Comment: А зачем вы с нулем сравниваете? Условие должно быть просто `(args[0].equals("First"))` - оно вернет `true` если в args[0] содержится строка "First"

Comment: C:\>javac Main.java

C:\>java Main
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
        at Main.main(Main.java:10)

C:\>java Main First
1
2
3
4
5

C:\>java Main Second
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
        at Main.main(Main.java:17)

Comment: `int i = massive.length;` - индексы массива от `0` до `length - 1`

Comment: И ещё пару моментов не по самому вопросу: 1. С английского "massive" - переводится как "массивный". Для обозначения массива используйте слово "array". 2. Должно быть `args.length == 0 || args[0] == null`, а не наоборот, ибо в вашем варианте второе условие бессмысленно.

Comment: @Regent Спасибо большое, все работает

Comment: @zRrr  Спасибо большое, все работает

Answer (score 1):

Итак, добавлена защита от `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, проверки модифицированы(нет зависимости от регистра аргумента), первый цикл заменён на `for-each`, второй изменён так, что бы выводились все элементы массива и не вылетала ошибка.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        if (args.length == 1 && args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("First")) {
            for (int anArray : array) 
                System.out.println(anArray);
        } else if (args.length == 1 && args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("Second")) {
            for (int i = array.length-1; i >= 0; i--) 
                System.out.println(array[i]);
        } else if (args.length == 0) 
            System.out.println("Third");
    }
```

Запускать стоит через консоль, командой java Main First/Second
Если есть возможность задать входные параметры посредством IDE, как например, в Intellij IDEA, то их можно задать примерно так: Run -> Edit Configuration -> Application в поле Program Arguments указываешь аргумент(если аргументов несколько, то указывать стоит через пробел).

Comment: Что насчет [этого комментария](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/562634/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8b-args#comment732899_562634), он верный, а ваш код упадет по выходу из диапазона

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего вы не правильно передаете параметры при запуске программы.
Это нужно делать так

```
java <Название класса с методом main> <первый параметр> <второй параметр>
```

Подробнее об этом можно почитать [здесь](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html)